# Is this the right way to unit test using JUnit and mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Is this the correct way to do a unit test my controller class?
Since my method to check if a given param is null or not is in my service class and I cannot call my service call from the controller in unit testing I mocked my service class such that, whenever this service method gets called, I mocked it to return true, I don't know if this is correct or not, can anyone clarify it for me and provide me an explanation on how to do right unit testing, since I am new to unit testing this is new to me:

my controller class :

```
public class MyClass{

@Autowired
private MyService myservice;

    @PostMapping("/sendNotificationToUsers")
        public ResponseEntity<?> myFunction(@RequestBody MyModelClass myModelClass, HttpServletRequest request) {
            if (myservice.isNull(myModelClass.getPID())) {
                    logging.error(ErrorMessages.ErrorLogs.NULL_PID.getMessage());
                    throw new CustomException(ErrorCodes.NULL_PID);
            }
    }

}
```

my service class :

```
public class MyService{
        public boolean isNull(String str){
              return str == null;
    }
}
```

My test class :

```
@SpringBootTest
public MyTestClass{

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private MyService myservice;

    private final MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();

    @Test
    public void nullPidTest(){
        MyModelClass myModelClass = new MyModelClass();
        myModelClass.setPID(null)
        
        when(myservice.isNull(myModelClass.getPID())).thenReturn(true);

        try{
              myClass.myFunction(myModelClass,request);
           }catch(CustomException e){
                 assertTrue(e.getMessage.contains(ErrorCodes.NULL_PID))
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: No it isn't. If you don't want to use spring don't use `@SpringBootTest`. Use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension)`. Also the assertions can be better use `assertThrows` instead of a try/catch.

Comment: actually i have used custom error codes , and i need to check if those error codes are thrown or not, that is the reason i used try and catch , assertThrows works fines but with try and check I can cross verify it here, also if these are the only things which need to be covered , so may I assume the rest of all is correct ?

Comment: You can do additional asserts, else use the `AssertJ` version of the assertions and you can verify anything you want without a try/catch/.

Comment: Ok will use that, and thank you for the help Deinum.

Comment: @Faiz `assertThrows` returns the thrown exception if it matches the given type. That allows you to perform additional assertions. And it has one advantage over your current code - if the method does _not_ throw an exception, your current test will pass, but with `assertThrows` it will fail.

Comment: Why do you need to mock `isNull` which shouldn't be an instance level method in the first place. Just pass `null` as a parameter and use the real function. You shouldn't mock everything (even the Mockito docs mention that)

Comment: Error codes are mapped by SpringMVC so you need to start your spring application and use `MockMvc` to make "real" requests to the controller (with all the standard behavior of your application). You are trying to test the wrong thing at the wrong level of abstraction.